# Live templates in phpstorm - creates html tags instead of snippet

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to set up a simple snippet that writes out `<?php ?>` whenever i type `php + TAB`.

I set the context to be php files, but whenever I'm in a php file and write `php + TAB` it writes out `<php></php>`. So it seems that the HTML Zen Coding scheme is overriding my snippet. I use Zen coding a lot so I do not want to turn this off, but I would like my snippets to have higher priority. How can I fix this?

I did try to use the "apply now" button, as well as restarting PhpStorm.

Comment: Works for me with my settings (NOTE: no code completion popup -- just text + TAB in editor area). What is your Emmet/Code Completion settings (screenshots)?

Answer (score 1):

I had set the context to be php, but unlike Sublime Text which simply looks at file-extensions to determine the context, PhpStorm looks whether I am actually within a php context. Since I am trying to write php tags I am most obviously not.

I changed the context to HTML and it solved the problem.